# Comments please on seemingly 'Too Easy' method to verify receipts

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt

I believe that to say that receipt verification help from Apple is obfuscated is an understatement.

Somehow I have been able to put some code together that does not use OpenSSL or ASN1 which SEEMS TO WORK to let me get access to the Receipt Fields as readable strings for all receipts for a bundle (including the most current which may not have been even generated by the current device).

This is a work in process, as you can see by the todo's, but could someone tell me why I should not use this method because it just seems too easy from all that I have read on the subject?

Also can anyone help me with the todo's? Like what I need to do at todo1 and 2 (I think i can handle 3, 4 and 5)?

In my case I am scanning the 'latest_receipt_info' receipts from most recent to earliest until I find the in-app product_id I am interested in and then determining its expired status from 'expires_date_ms'.  Is that the proper way to determine current expired status of a product_id?

Anyway here it is:

```
NSURL *storeURL;
exms = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:@"exms"];  //globally defined elsewhere
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
int64_t nowms = 1000*[today timeIntervalSince1970];
if (nowms> exms){ //todo maybe give a week grace here
   isSubscribed= NO;  //globally defined elsewhere
   // Load the receipt from the app bundle.
   NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
   NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
   if (!receipt) { /* No local receipt -- handle the error. */ }  //todo1

   /* ... Now Send the receipt data to server ... */
   // Create the JSON object that describes the request
   NSError *error;
   NSDictionary *requestContents = @{@"receipt-data": [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0],
                                     @"password": @"put your shared secret here"};
   NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestContents options:0 error:&error];

   if (!requestData) { /* ... Handle error ... */ } //todo2

   NSString *file=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iTunesMetadata.plist"];
   if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file]) {
      // probably a store app
      storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];  //todo3 test this for sure rather than ifdef debug
   }else{
      storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];
   }

   NSMutableURLRequest *storeRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:storeURL];
   [storeRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [storeRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];

   // Make a connection to the iTunes Store on a background queue.
   NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:storeRequest queue:queue
                          completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                             if (connectionError) {
                                /* ... Handle error ... */ //todo4
                             } else {
                                int64_t edms= 0;
                                NSError *error;
                                NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

                                if (!jsonResponse) { /* ... Handle error ...*/ }   //todo5

                                // Get object from the root object
                                NSArray *dictionaryObject = (NSArray *)[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"latest_receipt_info"];

                                NSDictionary *rcpt;
                                for (int i=[dictionaryObject count]-1;i>-1;i--){
                                   rcpt= [dictionaryObject objectAtIndex:i];
                                   NSString *pid= [rcpt objectForKey:@"product_id"];
                                   if ([pid isEqualToString:@"put your in-app purchase you are interested in here"]){
                                      edms= [[rcpt objectForKey:@"expires_date_ms"] longLongValue];
                                      break;
                                   }
                                }

                                NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
                                int64_t nowms = 1000*[today timeIntervalSince1970];
                                if (nowms> edms){
                                   isSubscribed= NO;
                                }else{
                                   isSubscribed= YES;
                                }
                                exms= edms;
                                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setDouble:exms forKey:@"exms"];
                                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                                if (isSubscribed== YES) _isexpiredView.hidden= true;

                             }
   }];
}else{
   isSubscribed= YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mechanical steps of receipt validation aren't hard and your implementation addresses these.  Doing it securely is more difficult as you cannot trust the end-user device.

The first issue I see is that you are storing the expiration date in NSUserDefaults and you only validate the receipt if "now" is after the expiration date.  So I can simply put an expiration date far into the future into NSUserDefaults and you will never expire the subscription nor check to see if the expiration date is valid.  Using an encrypted value and storing in the keychain would make it more secure.

Secondly you are validating the receipt directly from the device to the Apple server.  From the [Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1)

> Use a trusted server to communicate with the App Store. Using your own
>   server lets you design your app to recognize and trust only your
>   server, and lets you ensure that your server connects with the App
>   Store server. It is not possible to build a trusted connection between
>   a user’s device and the App Store directly because you don’t control
>   either end of that connection.

What this is saying is that by connecting directly from your device you make it easy for someone to spoof the Apple Server.  If you validated that the receipt was signed by Apple then this would be harder, but as it is you blindly trust the expiration date in the receipt.

Your approach is OK as long as you trust your users are honest.

Comment: Thank-you for taking the time to understand what I did.  I stored the value in NSUserdefaults so I did not have to 'bother' the Apple server until after the original receipt is expired, I can easily remove that feature.  As far as validating by connecting directly from the device is concerned, wouldn't that be covered by the fact that the Apple server is responding to a 'real' encrypted and embedded receipt that is sent to it, how can someone 'spoof' that?

Comment: But you don't know that you are talking to the Apple server.  You could be talking to a server pretending to be the Apple server.  You are suppling the receipt you got from the local device - which you can't trust and talking to a server you can't verify.

Comment: Can a non-jailbroken iPhone have software on it that intercepts and redirects my request or are you saying that all requests from my device can be 'illegally' redirected after my iPhone sends the request out?  And doesn't the response I receive have to come from the actual URL I request from? Sorry, not familiar with URLrequest security.

Comment: It is easier on a jailbroken device but even without jailbreaking it is fairly trivial to intercept the request through a proxy or DNS server setting. If you validate the digital certificates and receipt signatures then you are probably ok on a non-jailbroken device as the user can't tamper with the root certificate store

Comment: Thanks but validating digital certificates and receipt signatures is greek to me.  I am amazed. it looks like this issue has been around for over 2 years and Apple still expects us developers to be the ones jousting with the hackers.  There should be a well documented secure Apple method to do this! I think I will just trust my users. I can't even find documentation on what receipts I get back from my request in a sandbox account.  I keep getting receipts that seem to extend the expire date by an hour without making another purchase.  Thanks, Carmen

Comment: Paulw11 : **[Link]**(http://www.macworld.com/article/1167677/hacker_exploits_ios_flaw_for_free_in_app_purchases.html) from 2 years ago, seems to suggest that even verifying from my own server can be dangerous with a little work (and the hackers have had 2 years now to do that work).

Comment: Is there a way to verify the returned receipt is from Apple with the 'Shared Secret' method, I have to supply a shared secret going out but I can see no way to find a shared secret in the return. If there is a return secret, where is it and where do I find out what it should be as it can't be the same secret as I send out?

Comment: I think my sandbox account is just auto-renewing itself as it should (1 year compressed to ~ 1 hr) and 3 months free trial was 15 minutes.  WOW I figured that out myself :)  As far as shared secrets go they are probably useless unless encrypted, right?

Comment: The shared secret is set in iTunesConnect.  This helps you validate that the receipt came from Apple - but only if the validation is performed between your server and Apple's servers. If you perform the validation on the device then the receipt can be intercepted and the shared secret obtained.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56680/discussion-between-paulw11-and-carm100).